# Переход по ссылке по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: php

Какой скрипт нужен для того, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в программе PHP, переходило на ссылку?

Comment: Какой скрипт, в какой программе, какая кнопка? Пхп вообще с кнопками не работает, не считая винбиндера. Что вы хотите сделать с каким результатом?

Comment: header("Location: адрес ссылки"); :-D

Comment: @mihai567 [прочтите][1] и подумайте нада ли оно вам)


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142504/

Answer (score 3):

Может html?

```
<a href='http://***'><button>Кнопка с текстом</button></a>
      <a href='http://***'><button><img src="images/umbrella.gif" alt="Зонтик" 
              style="vertical-align: middle"> Кнопка с рисунком</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет надобности в передачи данных, то привязывать события лучше через js. Будет быстрее. Иначе вариант обработки запроса, посланного при нажатии на кнопку, и как выше ответили обработать header, но тогда получится двойное обновление страницы.

Comment: А [прогрессивная деградация](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) побоку? Неужели вручную на html недостаточно концептуально?

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что ТС'у нужно было 23 августа 2011 это)

```
echo '<a href="http://site.com">site.com</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**rasmisha**, Возможно вы имеете в виду target?

<a href="logs.txt" target="_blank"><button>Logs</button></a>